# CSS Shapes not drawing correctly in Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

Trying to draw some custom shapes in Bootstrap - they work perfectly in HTML and CSS, but Bootstrap warps them. It doesn't look like there are classes that overlap. Do some of the elements need to be labelled '!important'?

```
 <div class="pot-top"></div>
 <div class="pot-top-shadow"></div>
 <div class="pot-bot"></div>


.pot-top{
            width: 100px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: #FF7043;
            top: 200px;
            left: 300px;
            position: absolute;
        }
        .pot-bot{
            width: 50px;
            height: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            border-left: 15px solid transparent;
            border-right: 15px solid transparent;
            border-top: 50px solid #FF7043 ;
            top: 220px;
            left: 310px;
            z-index: 5;

        }
        .pot-top-shadow{
            width: 72px;
            height: 0px;
            position: absolute;
            border-left: 5px solid transparent;
            border-right: 5px solid transparent;
            border-top: 10px solid #F4511E ;
            top: 220px;
            left: 310px;
            z-index: 10;

        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't have thought you need to use `!important` on CSS classes that you invented but it is of course often useful on any standard Bootstrap classes. Could you edit and add any CSS that you're using as well please @bbsnax.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the way bootstrap uses border-box. If you go into the inspect menu and turn off the reboot.scss before/after pseudo classes for box-sizing you'll see it's fixed. I can't explain how this works, someone with more CSS knowledge will need to do that.

How I fixed it was increasing the width of your elements by the sum of the left & right borders.

```
.pot-bot{
    width: 80px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 15px solid transparent;
    border-right: 15px solid transparent;
    border-top: 50px solid #FF7043 ;
    top: 220px;
    left: 310px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.pot-top-shadow{
    width: 82px;
    height: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #F4511E ;
    top: 220px;
    left: 310px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

A better solution (maybe?) would be to use CSS clip-path (note you will need to fiddle with the values here so it looks correct). Funnily enough I still needed to increase the width of your divs to make it look like your test. [This](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) is the path generator I used.

```
.pot-bot{
    width: 80px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #FF7043;
    clip-path: polygon(20% 100%, 80% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
    top: 220px;
    left: 310px;
    z-index: 5;
}
.pot-top-shadow{
    width: 82px;
    height: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #F4511E;
    clip-path: polygon(5% 100%, 95% 100%, 100% 0, 0 0);
    top: 220px;
    left: 310px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```